# SQL - MAXDOP - From Variable

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

For some reason you cant set the MAXDOP amount from a variable.
Any way around it?

I do not want to use Dynamic SQL....

```
DECLARE @int INT = 1
SELECT COUNT(*) AS MyCount FROM dbo.TableName
OPTION (MAXDOP @int);
```

I am using SQL Server 2014

***Update:
There is more to my reason behind my madness. We want to see how say Purchases is running and control the MAXDOP from a value in a table, if it is killing the server we want to reduce the MAXDOP without changing the code.***

Comment: MAXDOP is more appropriately set at the server level. changing it dynamically on a per statement level is not a great idea...You may have an XY problem....What's the actual problem rather than your perceived solution...? Not my downvote btw

Comment: We need to be able to run MAXDOP on different areas and dont want to have it on the server layer.

Comment: "We need to be able to run MAXDOP on different areas" -that's not the actual problem! That's your attempted solution....

Comment: Those who down graded the question, please explain why?

Comment: It is set at the server level... you just may not be aware or like what it is set to. [Check out this quick thread](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/09/five-sql-server-settings-to-change/)

Comment: @ scsimon: it can bet set at a statement level; it's just that it's not always the right solution.

Comment: The DV is probably from people not reading the question IMHO

Comment: Not my downvote but if there ever was an xy problem this is it. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I agree @MitchWheat but I as only stating that it is also set at the server level and this setting would be used when not changed at the statement level... no?

Comment: @ scsimon: : your statement is "It is set at the server level", which could be misinterpreted. Yes, the server level will be used if not overridden at statement level.

Comment: Hi all, please see my Update.......

Comment: if you have a performance problem, use the 'right' indexes....your solution is an XY solution...

Comment: This may answer your question: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1426263-392-1.aspx

Comment: Yeah changing MAXDOP on a per table basis according to some value in a table is not the way to solve the performance challenges. Proper indexing and other tuning techniques is the right way to tackle this.

Comment: Five downvotes now and still no explanation.  I upvoted out of a sense of fairness.

Answer (score 2):

> There is more to my reason behind my madness. We want to see how say Purchases is running and control the MAXDOP from a value in a table, if it is killing the server we want to reduce the MAXDOP without changing the code.

You are describing [Resource Governor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/resource-governor?view=sql-server-2017). You should classify these queries into a non-critical resource pool, and constrain the resources they can consume. The link has the details, since this is a lengthy topic.

For the record, there is a way to control DOP of a query w/o altering the SQL text: [plan guides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/plan-guides?view=sql-server-2017):

```
sp_create_plan_guide   
  @name = N'Guide2',   
  @stmt = N'SELECT COUNT(*) AS MyCount FROM dbo.TableName',  
  @type = N'SQL',  
  @module_or_batch = NULL,   
  @params = NULL,   
  @hints = N'OPTION (MAXDOP 1)';
```

The `@hints` is still going to be dynamic SQL. And the plan guide is for every execution of the same query text. I would argue that resource governance is superior in every aspect.

Answer (score 1):

While I believe that the previous answer is the most appropriate, if you want to avoid dynamic SQL, the more appropriate question to ask is why would your server resources be so high that you want or need to reduce the MAXDOP on individual queries? Maybe the better approach is to benchmark your database performance, and optimize the queries or procedures that are procuring an abnormal amount of the system resources.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. Regular variables don't work. SQLCMD variables don't work. Can't use Dynamic SQL... How about this atrocity.

```
DECLARE @testVariable INT = 2;

IF @testVariable = 1 SELECT 1 OPTION (MAXDOP = 1);

IF @testVariable = 2 SELECT 1 OPTION (MAXDOP = 2);

IF @testVariable = 3 SELECT 1 OPTION (MAXDOP = 3);

IF @testVariable = 4 SELECT 1 OPTION (MAXDOP = 4);
```

Alternatively, you could just buckle, and use the Dynamic SQL.